# Circle A collides with both halves of circle B

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I cant seem to be able to solve a math problem related to collision detection.

I got the basic idea. Find the difference between two opposite x and y values.  Calculate the distance by multiplying the two results by itself to get the distance and then a check to see if the two balls collide. Then checking if any part of the angles intersect. Honestly it works somewhat but is still broken.

**Problem:** When starting the game and I let the ball collide with the visible half then the collison works and when the ball enters the non visible area the collision returns false. At the other hand, when restarting and letting it collide with the non visible area the collision returns true, then false when it enters the visible part of the semicircle.

What could it be? I suspect something due to my rotation. This is honestly weird. Here a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/2rz296tf/17/

Below the essential formula that makes it "kind of" work:

```
var dx = a - b;
var dy = a - b;
var semi = Math.atan2(dx, dy)
var distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

var hit = (distance < radiusA + radiusB) && (semi >= 0 && semi < angleB);
```

Comment: Assuming 2 circles of equal radii, CircleA extends into both halves of target CircleB when centerPointA is closer than radiusB to centerPointB. This is true regardless of the angle of attack. *Or are you testing if CircleA intersects 2 **specific** semi-circle parts of CircleB?* Please clarify :-)

Comment: @markE hey, sure. I am testing for intersection with the line segments of the arc. I want to test the exact point of collision of the animated ball with the giant semi circle, but only the semi circle. This, however is not the case.

Comment: @markE here another demo with the desired result. http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/fw9u73xc/

Comment: @markE I think the rotation screws it up since it works in the second fiddle. To test it just click somewhere in the preview and you will see what I mean

Comment: I'm feeling dense today so maybe I'm asking the obvious: Do you want to known when over half the area of the approaching circle is contained in the gray semi-circle?

Comment: @markE yes. Well not contained but "touches". So in the exact moment where the approaching circle touches the gray semi circle. Read your profile by the way, awesome stuff.

Comment: @markE does that help in any way?

Comment: @markE I will answer with yes to your question. Do you have an advice in  regards to the issue?

Comment: wouldn't `( distance < 0.5* ( radiusA + radiusB ) ) ` be enough ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing an angle to a length: `semi < radiusB`. That doesn't make any sense. You should compare `semi` to the orientation of your shield, not with its radius.

Looking at your code, you should do something like `semi >= angle - Math.PI && semi <= angle` instead. You'll need to implement a way to deal with the fact that angles run from -pi to pi and then loop around.

Comment: oh damn, its supposed to be the angle

Comment: I fixed the typo but it still works on both sides. Well everytime I restart and check one side it collides but not with the other and viceversa.

Comment: I don't see your code updating `player.shield.angle` anywhere.

Comment: (distance < enemy.radius + player.shield.radius) && (semi >= 0 && semi < player.shield.angle)

Comment: here the jsfiddle again: jsfiddle.net/2rz296tf/18

Comment: I mean that the variable `player.shield.angle` doesn't seem to ever change its value in your code.

Comment: Its not supposed to change. It doesnt really have to. It stays static.

Comment: Then how can it encode the orientation of the shield?

Comment: Well you are right in that point. Im not entirely sure how to fix this. I mean if I change the value of the angle then the shields actual angle will change and get bigger or smaller. The calculation should take care of it though since I passed some stuff into the arc tangent function as you can see and checked for intersection against a specific angle

Comment: You should compare to something that describes the angle of your shield, which apparently in your code is `angle` and not `player.shield.angle`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Why didnt I think about this earlier. Indeed, I was only affecting one side of the PI, either negative or positive and should have added a second condition